# Infer the variable type from function parameters

Tags: typescript

A middleware function `getSession(request, opts): void` retrieves a `session` from the database and attaches it to the `request`, using some `opts`.

- If the route is not protected, it will return early;
- If the route is protected and no `account` is stored for the `session`, it will redirect to the /home route;
- If the route is protected and no `profile` is stored for the `session`, it will redirect to the /create-profile route.

Thus, a `request.session` will have either:

- No `account`,
- An `account`, or
- An `account` and a `profile`.

**Problem:**

How can I infer the type of `request.session` by the `request` and `opts` provided to  `getSession()`?

**Example:**

The current types, implementation and usage of `getSession()` are provided below.

```js
// utils/types.ts

interface Session {
  id: number;
  // ...
  account: Account | null;
}

interface Account {
  id: number;
  // ...
  profile: Profile | null;
}

interface Profile {
  id: number;
  // ...
}

interface HttpRequest extends Request {
  session: Session;
}
```

```js
// utils/session.ts

const getSession = async (request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected?: boolean } = {}) => {
  // Set request.session as session retrieved from database
  // EXAMPLE: session with an account and no profile
  request.session = { id: 1, account: { id: 1, profile: null } };

  // If route is not protected: return early
  if (!opts.protected) {
    return;
  }

  // If route is protected and there is no account: redirect to /home route
  if (!request.session.account) {
    throw new Response(null, { status: 302, headers: { Location: "/home" } });
  }

  // If route is protected and there is no profile: redirect to /create-profile route
  if (!request.session.account?.profile) {
    throw new Response(null, { status: 302, headers: { Location: "/create-profile" } });
  }
};
```

```js
// routes/create-profile.tsx

const loader = async (request: HttpRequest) => {
  try {
    await getSession(request, { protected: true });

    // TODO:
    // Infer if the request.session has an account or profile after calling getSession()
    // EXAMPLE:
    // If route is protected and no redirect to /home page:
    // Infer that there is an account, i.e. request.session.account is not null
    const account = request.session.account;

    return null;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB5lnw) with an assertion function, but then `getSession` can't be `async` (and you can't have an async assertion function). Otherwise, I don't know if this specific behavior is possible...

Comment: There is no way to express this in TypeScript currently; see [microsoft/TypeScript#37681](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681) for the feature request.  As a workaround you could have `getSession()` return the narrowed request and you use that instead of your original variable.  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mppRXm) shows.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for links to the feature request and workaround. The workaround does fully address my question, so feel free to write up an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR this is not currently possible as asked. You could work around it by having `getSession()` return its input as a narrowed type and have the caller use the return value.

---

You would like `getSession(request, options)` to act as an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) (at least when `options.protected` is `true`) that [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of `request` from `HttpRequest` to a type where `request.session.account.profile` is known to be defined.  That is, from `HttpRequest` to the equivalent of `HttpRequest & {session: {account: {profile: Profile}}}`.

If `getSession()` were a synchronous function, you could give it the following call signatures:

```
declare function getSessionSync(
  request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected: true }
): asserts request is HttpRequest & { session: { account: { profile: Profile } } };
declare function getSessionSync(
  request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected?: false }
): void;
```

And see it work as desired:

```
(request: HttpRequest) => {
  try {
    getSessionSync(request, { protected: true });
    const account = request.session.account;
    // const account: Account & { profile: Profile; }
    account.profile.id; // okay
    return null;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, `getSession()` is an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and TypeScript does not currently support `async` assertion functions as of TypeScript 4.9.  There is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#37681](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681), so perhaps in some future version of TypeScript you'll be able to write

```
// NOT VALID TS, DO NOT TRY THIS
declare function getSession(
  request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected: true }
): Promise<asserts request is HttpRequest & {session: {account: {profile: Profile}}}>;
```

But for now you can't, and you'll need to work around it.

---

One workaround is to do what we had to do before assertion functions were introduced to the language: instead of trying to make the function narrow the type of its argument, have it return the argument as the narrowed type... and then use the returned value afterward instead of the argument.  Generally, instead of:

```
declare function f(x: A): asserts x is B;
declare const x: A;
acceptB(x); // error, x is not known to be B here
f(x);
acceptB(x); // okay, x has been narrowed to B
```

You could write:

```
declare function f(x: A): B;
declare const x: A;
acceptB(x); // error, x is not known to be B
const newX = f(x); // save result to a new variable
// use newX instead of x after this point
acceptB(newX); // okay, newX is known to be B
```

For your example code, this looks like:

```
declare function getSession(
  request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected: true }
): Promise<HttpRequest & { session: { account: { profile: Profile } } }>;
declare function getSession(
  request: HttpRequest, opts: { protected?: false }
): Promise<void>;

const loader = async (request: HttpRequest) => {
  try {
    const _request = await getSession(request, { protected: true });
    const account = _request.session.account;
    account.profile.id; // okay
    return null;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

This is clunkier than using an assertion function, but at least it works!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-PSP1IC+YJ9s2aQYAK15lMEACSdBElo1CcU9xjRkifhHjOXAQCcGBaYsZAIx8ACEmpQL2kS6sie6TljJ5DWWuww4o8OIyIyNki9NUYw9fBINdtDIFzwDPf9QinHwZCnJcAvPXIa7sJA7PUGoRObiT73ncARZ1lQtNlKQ12RKFIWm30sACRAHzzhgkZLKt05VQAzAADAATGCa64wcNBVbCR3sCuqxCAARArSsQKHAoKWUzOLHDCORBzwvTOjep8wL3vQSLz1g9ykvSzGcv+fApwrRAAC0+cq5tZTq6TWvBrrGb6pTRSxAbB5ZybZszPpVs2xYdv0r8K0iC7Htez7tD+0ggfB0ySDh2XuPUNXrbR0uiaXs0iz01wjONK6eKUfaJKlUCEbgpV2pU7VKJosgWItkrZIQAAPBSV9pnSsLa8ycW1UuSvy5AKDEHoyznyVEgb+OYKpamqtTA0RpMCmhfjyN+ywv4qh-pQSBGVmg3lcjBcU1xsrBndh8N6OZL7wJvogqM98MZxifuBJAmFChgHfjgp0aoGz-2DIAvWAMmEd25IUMB28IFCkgnxWy8EpRBgLJwKhNCHSwNwfQ8md8eZ6nqsadBPBOGLR4dhPgHpbTeGChgdgIBfZRQKu8IqtDNF8JJK6T0lFfSUVIMFAA+kNRxoUQBXSUTlYA0DQRIIfqwhMsdu7BX+lFQJOYPoqJ1v9MsXYRHty5AOPg6k0oEwPAfCGTNlwrXXJuaSXdSn3GxqeGgO4mZXiyLYIAA)

Answer (score 0):

So, basically your request goes through validation in getSession function and after it is validated you assume that it has specific properties. You can just create 2 types, like Session (where needed properties still might be undefined) and ValidSession (where you made sure that needed properties exist), make HttpRequest generic like

```
interface HttpRequest<SessionType> extends Request {
  session: SessionType
}
```

and make it the return type of your validation function. At the end you will have a function that receives HttpRequest, with possibly undefined properties, but returns HttpRequest with all properties that you need.

```
const validateRequest = (request: HttpRequest<Session>): HttpRequest<ValidSession> => { ... }
```